# Hypothesis Testing and Formatting Output

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to write a function that tests hypotheses and gives me a nice table but I can't.  I need forum's help. For example, I have the following data

```
data1 = RandomReal[{0, .5}, 100];
```

I want to test whether the mean of the data is significantly different form zero using t-test and produce a table that has mean of the data and t-value but mean should have *, ** or *** if the mean is significant at 1%,5% and 10% respectively and t-value should be in brackets such [t-value]. If I do the following code:

```
{If[Quiet[TTest[data1, Automatic, "PValue"]] <= .05, SuperStar[
  Mean[data1]], Mean[data1]], 
 Quiet[TTest[data1, Automatic, "TestStatistic"]]}
```

I get

[image]

However, I am trying to get

[image]

based on whether I have P - value <= 0.01 or  P - value <= 
 0.05 or P - value <= 0.1 respectively.

This problem may not look practical but I am trying to  apply this function to a data  with more than 20000 observations and 6 columns and I have to use the same test to different sub-samples and produce a table with mean and t-values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stars can be done with `Superscript`. Have a look at `ToString` and `StringJoin` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo[t1_: 0.01, t2_: 0.05, t3_: 0.1] := 
  Module[{m = Mean@#, p = Quiet@TTest[#, Automatic, "TestData"], s = {"", "*", "**", "***"}, c}, 
    c = # <= p[[2]] < #2 & @@@ Partition[{0, t1, t2, t3, Infinity}, 2, 1];
    {Which @@ Riffle[c, Superscript[ToString@m, #] & /@ s /. Superscript[x_, ""] :> x], 
     Row[{"[", p[[1]], "]"}]}] &;
```

Example:

```
data1 = RandomReal[{0, .5}, 20];

foo[][data1]
(* {0.282717, [8.44013]} *)

foo[][data1 - .2]
(* {0.0827171^*, [2.4694]} *)

foo[][data1 - .25]
(* {0.0327171^***, [0.976723]} *)
```

Comment: Thank you kguler. This is helpful. With this help, I will be able to get what I want.

Comment: @ramesh, my pleasure. The answer deals with formatting only. Not sure if i got the logic right -- the conditions/inequalities may be all mixed up :)